# What's the initial catalog in my SQL Server local database?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following connection string:

```
<add name="xx" 
  connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=abc;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\abc.mdf" 
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Can someone explain what is meant by the Initial Catalog. Can I have two connection strings that point to the same data file but different catalogs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initial Catalog is the DB on the server that the connection string is for.

Yes, you can have multiple connection strings that point to different DBs. Data Source will be the server name, Initial Catalog is the DB name.

**Edit:**
(Addressing comment here because it looked terrible in the comments)

Not sure what you mean by data file. Say you have a SQL Server instance set up on your local machine with two DBs in it named Geography and Reports. You could have two connection strings as follows:

```
<add name="Geo" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Geography;Trusted_Connection=True;persist security info=False;integrated security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

<add name="Rep" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Reports;Trusted_Connection=True;persist security info=False;integrated security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: But can those different databases still use the same data file?

Comment: Sorry but I am bit confused because my connection strings use AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\abc.mdf and your strings do not.

Comment: AttachDBFilename is unique to SQL Express, it spins up a user instance of SQL Express attached to a specific DB Filename for single user mode. You shouldn't need it at all except in specific circumstances. With Initial Catalog defined it is redundant.

Comment: I'm sorry. Can you explain why it's redundant? I think all the Msoft examples I see specify both an initial catalog and the .mdf filename. Are you saying that initial catalog somehow decides the name of the .mdf file?

Comment: No, they're independent and redundant with both of them. AttachDBFilename is only useful if the DB is not attached to the SQL Server instance. If your DB is attached to the instance of SQL Server then use Initial Catalog. Using both will be redundant because AttachDBFilename attaches that file name to the DB instance.

Answer (score 6):

The normal use for LocalDb is to use AttachDBFilename and the program will create some GUID like catalog name that is normally ignored. The SQL instance is created, if it doesn't exist, when the file is first accessed. The instance might not exist and might be deleted arbitrarily between uses. Everything revolves around the *.mdf file. These programs are also installed by end-users who aren't expected to do anything with SQL except have LocalDB installed.

What if you want to have a particular name for your database, so that you can easily interact reference it in the master? Then you need to use Initial Catalog as well. 
In particular I've found that if I don't use both then I can't detach my database from code using sp_detach_db in the master as I don't know the name.

Using both InitialCatalog and AttachDbFilename would not be redundant as you need AttachDBFilename at first since the database doesn't exist yet, just the file, and you need Initial Catalog to interact with the database int the master.

If I'm really wrong, then please correct me, as I've been using this technology for over a year and have many questions of my own that I've already asked that no ones answered.